# How to find the best combination of features which will maximise the probability of a particular class?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-selection

Suppose we have a classifier having two output classes C1 and C2 and 8 features X1, X2 ... X8. Now how do you find the combination of features (can be a subset as well) such that the likelihood of class C1 is maximized?

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/ - feature selection is a huge sub-topic itself in machine learning

Answer (score 0):

you could look at something called "backward elimination" to find the best combination of features which impact the outcome of each of the classes.To what I can interpret from your question, you want to maximize the likelihood of class C1(be biased basically),you could consider going for a weighted approach for the same(higher weights for the features which impact the outcome of class C1)